# Email cant get retrieved in php

Tags: email, php

I use php in webform to redirect to an URL after the form is submitted

```
$email = [submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_fieldset_fieldset:civicrm_1_contact_1_email_email:nolabel];

header('Location: /submit/send.php?email='.$email);
```

It doesnt work when I submit, it redirect me to :
`www.site.com/submit/send.php?email=`

if I change the `$email` to :

```
$email = [submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_fieldset_fieldset:civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_first_name:nolabel];
```

It does indeed redirect to `www.site.com/submit/send.php?email=myfirstname`

Why my email address is not working ? Any idea?

I found the same question here without any answer :
https://www.drupal.org/node/2767233

Comment: Hi Gustavo, can you give us a little more information about what you are working with, such as CiviCRM version and what CMS you are using. Also, can you better describe what you are trying to accomplish by adding PHP instead of using the tools available within the webform settings? Thanks!